# how to binding Select2 to string array tags?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a `select2` for add tags . in add new item i use this for add tags like this

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label asp-for="Words" class="control-label col-md-1"></label>
   <div class="col-md-7">
    <select asp-for="Words" class="form-control "></select>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Words, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
   </div>
</div>

 $("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.Words)").select2({
      tags: true
  });
```

i add tags in it and save to db, but in update mode don't fill `select` with items.
How to fill with tags in load form?

*words is Array string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to fill select with the value of Words?If so,you can use asp-items to set options of select.Also,you can pass other list to view,and fill `select`.Here is a demo to fill `select` with `Model.Words`:

Model:

```
public class Product
    {
        public List<string> Words { get; set; }

    }
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult TestProduct() {

            return View(new Product {  Words=new List<string> { "aa","bb","cc"} });
        }
```

View:

```
    <select asp-for="Words" class="form-control " multiple="multiple" asp-items="@Model.Words.Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Text=x,Value=x})"></select>
 $("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.Words)").select2({
      tags: true
  });
```

result:
[image]